# How is Julia's compilation cache managed?

Tags: julia

The Julia's JIT uses cache.

1) Is this cache being emptied once we restart Julia REPL? So that is why people tend not to restart the process?

2) But then restarts are sometimes needed, because that is what the Revise.jl helps avoid. So it means that sometimes by updating code or packages we end up with some code that is cached and this is a problem ... because it does not reflect our newest source code?

3) We can keep (between restarts) some of the cache produced by the JIT by saving it to userimg.jl file? This will increase the speed of first use of the functions included in this file. This can be done with  PackageCompiler.jl?

Comment: This is an internal detail which is currently being changed, so I'm not sure an answer here will be correct for more than 6 months. But yes, it creates some sort of cache that is then used to speed up first use, but a lot of that cache is currently discarded, and it's a non-breaking change to just cache it better and hence it was kept for post-1.0 work. I'm not sure this kind of discussion is really fit for the question and answer flow of SO though, so feel free to ask on the Discourse for a longer discussion.

Comment: This is also a really deep question — each point of which is at least a blog post.